# How to access the contens of a list using a vector of names in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list such as X, which contains certain entries X$(y1,...), the name of the entries are saved in a char vector named Y. Now I want to use mapply to access the contents of X$Y. I write the following mapply line:

```
aux<-mapply(function(x,y) x$y$family ,X,Y)
```

The objective being able to access the content "familly" without writing a loop.
I receive the following error

```
Error in x$y$family : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Where am I making the error?

For example:

```
 X<-list(x1=c(1,2),y1=c(3,4))
 Y<-c("x1","y1")
 aux<-mapply(function(x,y) x$y[[1]],X,Y)
```

I should like aux to be `c(1,3)`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  why do you need `mapply` to access the content.  If the names are stored in 'Y', why not use `X[Y]` to get the contents.  If you need to update the content of those list elements, then `X[Y] <- lapply(X[Y], somefunction)`

Comment: I added a small example. Check it out please.

Comment: Did you meant `Y <- c("x1", "y1")`

Comment: yes it weas a typo

Answer (score 1):

Use the names vector ("Y") to subset the elements of "X" i.e. `X[Y]`, loop through those with `sapply` and extract the first element from each of the `vector` in the `list`.

```
unname(sapply(X[Y], `[`, 1))
#[1] 1 3
```

If the "Y" vector contains all the `names` of the "X" element, there is no need to use `X[Y]` (as @Frank mentioned), just directly loop over the "X" and get the first element

```
unname(sapply(X, `[`, 1))
```

Comment: And if the OP is only interested in having Y=names(X), as seems to be the case, they can just use X instead of X[Y]

Comment: @Frank Yes, it is true

Comment: Actually I used lapply as you suggested and it works. Cheers :)